# attribute name "var" in javascript associative array

Tags: javascript, safari, specifications

Quick question out of curiosity:

code below works in Firefox and Chrome but not in Safari. Is this Javascript spec circumvented by Firefox and Chrome or is this a quirk in Safari?

```
 var a = {};
 a.var = "test";
```

in all (firefox, safari and chrome)

```
 a["var"] = "test";
 a.id = "another test";
```

works as expected.

Cheers,
Jeroen.

Comment: Being picky, JavaScript does not have associative arrays ;-)

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: Being picky, JavaScript noes not have arrays at all. ;-)

Comment: Gumbo - difficult to support that argument given the built-in Array constructor.

Comment: @RobG: ECMAScript does only have [nine data types](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-8): “There are nine types (Undefined, Null, Boolean, String, Number, Object, Reference, List, and Completion). Values of type Reference, List, and Completion […] cannot be stored as properties of objects.” Any other data type is just a specialization of them.

Comment: Just like the [Array object](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.4) where the indices are used as property names: “Array objects give special treatment to a certain class of property names. A property name P (in the form of a string value) is an array index if and only if ToString(ToUint32(P)) is equal to P and ToUint32(P) is not equal to 232 - 1.”

Comment: Gumbo - Types are irrelevant here. Your logic suggests that javascript doesn't have Functions, Dates, Errors, RegExps or even a global object. There is an Array constructor, it's illogical to argue that an instance created from `new Array()` or an array literal is not "an array". On the other hand, there is no "Associative Array" constructor or Type or similar value returned by the *typeof* operator. Arrays are objects because in the end, everything in javascript is an object, even null — except for undefined, but let's not go there. :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to the ecmascript specification its not allowed,

from ecmascript-262:http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf

```
7.6.1.1 Keywords
The following tokens are ECMAScript keywords and may not be used as Identifiers in ECMAScript programs.

break, do, instanceof, typeof, case, else, new, var, catch, finally, return, void, continue, for, switch, while, debugger, function, this, with, default, if, throw, delete, in, try
```

based on that safari is the preferred behavior

Comment: But the thing here is that a.var is not an identifier, but a property of the object a.

Comment: @erKURITA: In that expression, `var` **is** an identifier.

Comment: erKURITA - the explanation is in section 11.2.1 where dot notation is described as `MemberExpression.IdentifierName`

Answer (score 5):

`var` is a reserved keyword so it might break when being used without being quoted.

Comment: Yeah I that's what I though of as well but I'd expect that safari's parser would be able to distinguish between var a, and a.var. Chrome's and Firefox' are.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be that Chrome and Firefox make a clear distinction between identifiers (variables, objects, functions, etc...) and object properties. I tried with all the reserved words and, as an object they "work":

`var myObject = {
  new : 30,
  var: 20
}`

You can access each property and no SyntaxError would be thrown.